# Refactor (abstract) large form component so it is easier to read (React)

Tags: reactjs, forms, state

I am looking for an elegant way to structure my large form component. - My code roughly looks like the below example.

This is not easy for me to read and although I know this question is subjective to how a person prefers to work I would like to know how I would break this component down to be more legible.

Ideally, I want to split the functions within this single component to separate components. I am using a rough example from one of my own projects so I can better understand the best practice for this type of refactoring.

As you can see, onSubmit the form is programmed to render the code and also download the code. The form takes in state from multiple inputs and is meant to create an updated HTML file which is being returned using the Result function.

Now, this isn't working code but a rough example for all of the functions involved in my component. - The snippet will not run because ReactDomServer is being called to download the output as an HTML file using renderToStaticMarkup and this is not available in snippet.

Thank you in advance for any help in simplifying.

```js
function Result(props) {
    const { image, title, bodyText, btnText, btnUrl, btnColor } = props;

    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `
    <!doctype html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    
    <head>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
                  <div>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="vertical-align:top;padding:0px;">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" style="font-size:0px;padding:0px;word-break:break-word;">
                                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td style="width:600px;"> <img alt="" height="auto" src="" style="border:0;display:block;outline:none;text-decoration:none;height:auto;width:100%;"
                                            width="600"> </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>

    </body>
    
    </html>`}</div>;
}

function download(filename, text) {
    let element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute(
        'href',
        'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text)
    );
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
}

function BasicHtml(props) {
    const { title, children } = props;

    return (
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>{title}</title>
            </head>
            <body>{children}</body>
        </html>
    );
}

export default class FormComponent extends React.Component {
    state = { name: '', age: null, submitted: false };

    handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ submitted: true });
        this.generateHtmlFile();
    };

    generateHtmlFile = () => {
        const { name, age } = this.state;
        const formHtml = ReactDomServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
            <BasicHtml title={name}>
                <FormComponent />
            </BasicHtml>
        );
        const resultHtml = ReactDomServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
            <BasicHtml title={name}>
                <Result name={name} age={age} />
            </BasicHtml>
        );
        download('result.html', resultHtml);
        download('form.html', formHtml);
    };

    render() {
        const { name, age, submitted } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>
                        Name:{' '}
                        <input
                            name="name"
                            type="text"
                            value={this.state.name}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            required
                        />
                    </label>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <label>
                        Age:{' '}
                        <input
                            name="age"
                            type="number"
                            value={this.state.age}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            required
                        />
                    </label>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
                <br />
                {submitted ? <Result name={name} age={age} /> : null}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
        
        ReactDOM.render(<FormComponent />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Forms tend to end up looking like jumbled messes, they are usually the ugliest part of any React app.  What I suggest breaking down all the components into separate functional component files, and store them just outside the parent component in another folder.  Store values using a global store like Redux or Context API, and dispatch and run onSubmit-like functions outside the parent component.  Also, separate and re-use the render logic for various forms as much as possible, importing JSX is the easiest part.

Comment: Are you familiar with create-react-app?  If not, I suggest looking onto that and taking some basic react courses online.  I'm happy to share some resources that have helped me if you would like them.

Comment: @dandmcd Thank you for the tips. Do you have a good example that showcases context be used with forms that have multiple functions like this?

Comment: @AdamHinckley I am familiar with CRA, currently using Gatsby for this form. Do you know of any lessons that encompass the issue I am having? I've seen a few tutorials that use abstractions, however, I have not seen any that match my form example.

Comment: @Dr.Tenma thanks for sharing more context.  I have only dabbled in gatsby a little bit.  Why are you using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?  Also if you have a link to a repo we can take a look at, that would be helpful.